# Upload a file from custom component folder when installing the component

Tags: component, development, joomla-api, file-upload

I know how to upload file given from jform if a component is already installed. But how to upload a file from my admin/assets/ folder of my component when installing the component? In my script.php I try the following code:

```
jimport('joomla.filesystem.folder');
jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');
...
public function install($parent)
{
   // creating a folder
   $path = JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "templates" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "isis" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "html" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "com_content" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "article";
   $mode = 0755;
   JFolder::create($path, $mode);

   // uploading a file
   $file = JPATH_COMPONENT_ADMINISTRATOR . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "assets" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "edit.php";
   $filename = JFile::makeSafe($file['name']);
   $src = $file['tmp_name'];
   $dest = JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "templates" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "isis" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "html" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "com_content" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "article" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename;
   JFile::upload($src, $dest);
}
```

The folder is being created successfully but the file is not being uploading to the folder and I get the can't move error

Comment: Are you sure you're not trying to **move** a file instead? Is this a file that comes as part of your component zip file?

Comment: Yes, it's the part of my component. But I thought **uploading** and **moving** a file are the same no matter where the file comes from

Answer (score 1):

Do your file movement tasks in postflight function of your script.php file

```
function postflight($type, $parent) 
{
  // do it here
  JFile::move($src, $dest);
}
```

This function get called after copying files from your package, databases gets updated etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have got muddle up here. When you install an extension, you already uploading a zip file. So once Joomla had processed this zip, the files are already on the server. You cannot "*upload*" a file from one directory to another. You need to "*move*" or "*copy*" it.

You the code you'll need to use will either be:

```
JFile::move($src, $dest);
```

or:

```
JFile::copy($src, $dest);
```

And as @Nagarjun already said, you need to put this code in the `postflight` function rather than the `install` function. Ig you use the `install` function, the `$src` file that you define may not yet exist ;)

Hope this helps

Answer (score -2):

Here you can find a brief example of Joomla installer script file,

- https://docs.joomla.org/Manifest_files#Script_file
- https://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Adding_an_install-uninstall-update_script_file

Comment: I think you missing the actual question here. It's not so much which function to put the code in, but the actual code itself

Comment: Shared those core link with intention that @stckvrw can get more idea about what functions are available in install script.